# Entity Framework: How to have 2 properties referring to same other table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So imagine I have a simple database for a system that can receive boxes (incoming) and send boxes (outgoing). So one box has multiple boxcontent, but "a" boxcontent can have an incoming box (when it arrived) but also an outgoing box (when it gets sent away).

But when I have a structure like this, Entity Framework adds a "Box_ID" column to the database table of BoxContent.

Here's the entities:

```
public class BoxContentItem {
    public Box IncomingBox { get; set; }
    public Box OutgoingBox { get; set; }
}

public class Box {
    public IList<BoxContentItem> BoxContentItems { get; set; }
}
```

So how do I make `IList<BoxContent> BoxContent` link to either `Box IncomingBox` or `Box OutgoingBox`?

Comment: So 1 Box can have multple Contents? Dont you want 1 Box - 1 Content?

Comment: No, it's just a simple example, a box can have multiple content, but I'll rename it for easier understanding

Comment: I would do only 1 ``public Box Box { get; set; }`` and in Box add a new member ``public bool IsOutgoing { get; set; }`` or a enum that specifies the type. ``public BoxType Type { get; set; }``

Comment: Yes, but in the context of my project, it helps a lot being able to refer to both incoming and outgoing box from the boxContentItem

Comment: So a ``BoxContentItem`` can have at the same time an ``IncomingBox`` and an ``OutgoingBox``? I understood its either the one or the other. Dont think EF can merge those stuff, you will need 2 different lists. ``public IList<BoxContentItem> OutgoingContentItems { get; set; }`` and ``public IList<BoxContentItem> IncomingContentItems { get; set; }``, if you want a merged list you will have to do ``public IList<BoxContentItem> AllContentItems { get { return new List<BoxContentItem>(this.OutgoingContentItems.Concat(this.IncomingContentItems); } }`` dont think there is another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use InverseProperty Attribute on Box entity, but you need to add additional property like:

```
public class Box {
    [InverseProperty("IncomingBox")]
    public IList<BoxContentItem> IncomingBoxContentItems { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("OutgoingBox")]
    public IList<BoxContentItem> OutgoingBoxContentItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! Some queries from the database needed to be changed (the includes) but everything else works just as I wished for. Thanks!